# "Could not resolve host: download.docker.com" while installing docker CE

Tags: docker, installation

I am getting this error while installing docker CE on my `ubuntu` machine

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: download.docker.com
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

While performing the step

```
Add Docker’s official GPG key:
$ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

as mentioned here https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-docker-ce-1

Comment: I am also experiencing this problem. Can reach download.docker.com from Chrome, but can't from Firefox and curl

Answer (score 27):

By forcing curl and apt to use ipv4, `download.docker.com` is resolved correctly.
in curl, add the **-4** argument

```
 Add Docker’s official GPG key:
$ curl -4fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

then to force apt to use ipv4 => https://www.vultr.com/docs/force-apt-get-to-ipv4-or-ipv6-on-ubuntu-or-debian

Comment: While providing links is useful, it would be MORE helpful to the asker if you posted a summary of the steps involved on the link you posted.  Can you please elaborate on the part that says "to force apt to use ipv4"? Links can go dead any time. For more tips, see [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 10):

It's just a random error (may happens due to instable Internet, DNS caching ...)

In my case just opening "https://download.docker.com/" in my browser (to make sure Internet is working and the docker website is up) resolved the problem

Answer (score 6):

In my case disconnecting from VPN solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If the problem persists, then change/add your DNS server to google DNS servers : 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4

You can try the below commands before changing your DNS server :

dig @8.8.8.8 download.docker.com

dig @8.8.4.4 download.docker.com

If you are on ubuntu, then try the below link to change the DNS server :
https://askubuntu.com/a/820873/707990

Answer (score 3):

1. Adding -4 helped to resolve the issue, however, I got another error:

curl -4fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failedbuntu1.1)

2. Then I followed this answer: [How to connect to the agent: IPC connect call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61463220/how-to-connect-to-the-agent-ipc-connect-call)

and it worked:

curl -4fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

OK

However, I got W: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'download.docker.com' error from sudo apt-get update

3. The last issue got resolved by running:

echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null

Answer (score 1):

**Manually Add GPG Key**

If that does not work then click on the link to download gpg key and then manually add it

```
sudo apt-key add '/home/user/Downloads/gpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set proxy in ubuntu. It workd for me.

```
export https_proxy=<YOUR_PROXY_ADDRESS:PORT>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred when system is not able to connect to internet properly. If you are doing it in virtual machine then change the network type from **NAT** to **bridged**.
After changing it check internet connection is working properly you can check docker download page.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

what fixed it for me - switch iptables to legacy mode:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config iptables
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to */etc/resolv.conf* and add

**nameserver 8.8.8.8**

which is the google dns server