# How to connect to the agent: IPC connect call

Tags: windows, docker, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu `(VERSION="20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)` on Windows 10. Itried to install Docker.
I'm following the Docs from docs.docker.com:
I run the two commands:

```
$ curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
$ sudo sh get-docker.sh
```

When I run the second command it return an error:

```
Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed
```

I looked in internet I found that some links trying to resolve the issue but in vein.
[gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46673717/gpg-cant-connect-to-the-agent-ipc-connect-call-failed)
https://michaelheap.com/gpg-cant-connect-to-the-agent-ipc-connect-call-failed/

Someone have a suggestion please ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The temporary workaround mentioned on the issue thread at https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5125#issuecomment-625985191 worked for me. Run the commands

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~rafaeldtinoco/+archive/ubuntu/lp1871129/+files/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu8+lp1871129~1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg --install libc6_2.31-0ubuntu8+lp1871129~1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-mark hold libc6 #to avoid further update
```

Edit: /var/lib/dpkg/info/libc6:amd64.postinst and remove the sleep 1 like so:

Change this: 
[image]

To this:

[image]